# Problema com função que gera url amigável

Tags: php, mysql

Boas

Tenho uma função que me gera o nome para as urls amigáveis mas estou a ter um problema que quando a função gera o nome se esse nome conter acentos ela não coloca a mesma palavra mas sem acento coloca outro caracter

Função

```
function url_amigavel($string) {
        $palavra = strtr($string, "ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ", "SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy");
        $palavranova = str_replace("_", " ", $palavra);
        $pattern = '|[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]|';    $palavranova = preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $palavranova);
        $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $palavranova);
        $string = str_replace('---', '-', $string);
        $string = str_replace('--', '-', $string);
        return strtolower($string);
    }
```

Por exemplo

César Sousa

Deveria de converter em cesar-sousa
Mas esta a converter assim
c-sar-sousa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para limpar qualquer coisa que você queira botar em uma URL você pode usar a seguinte função (que usa [iconv](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.iconv.php)):

```
function sanitize_title($title) {
    // substitui espaços por "-"
    $title = preg_replace('#\s+#', '-', $title);

    // faz a transliteração pra ASCII
    $title = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $title);

    // remove qualquer outra coisa inválida da url
    $title = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+#', '', $title);

    return $title;
}
```

Antes de chamar esta função é bom que você use [`setlocale`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setlocale.php) para que a transliteração funcione corretamente:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8');
```

---

Exemplo:
    echo sanitize_title('César Sousa');
    echo sanitize_title('áéíóú@#_888999-teste outras  palavras');

Gera:

```
cesar-sousa
aeiou_888999-teste-outras-palavras
```

[Veja um teste no ideone](https://ideone.com/LkTXMJ)

Comment: Realmente com a função que o @P. Santos colocou funcionou mas em alguns reparei que não estava a funcionar bem mas com essa funcionou certinho obrigado aos dois pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Uma função simples que funciona comigo:

```
function url_amigavel($string){
    return preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities($string));
}
```

Algo mais completo seria:

```
function url_amigavel($string){
    $url = str_replace(' ', '_', $string);
    $url = preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities($url));

    return strtolower($url);
}
```

Veja aqui o teste:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que funcione

Abs

Comment: Testei aqui mas nao funcionou não converte nenhum caracter

Comment: Olá @CésarSousa, adicionei uma imagem com o teste feito comm sucesso. Dê uma olhada.

Comment: Testei com essa nova mais completa e funcionou direitinho. obrigado já tinha testado muitas e nenhuma resolveu

Comment: Dependendo do que for passado, `htmlentities` vai gerar caracteres especiais e a URL vai ficar quebrada.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro poderia por favor citar um exemplo em que isso poderia acontecer para eu poder testar aqui?

Comment: @P.Santos Dá uma olhada [neste teste no ideone](https://ideone.com/21TWtV)